# Open another .exe from nwjs app

Tags: nw.js

I have created an app in nw.js & it is running fine.

I have a requirement that I create a button in nwjs app (html page), and its click should open another .exe file in the user system(probably in the same directory along with nwjs.exe).

Can I do that and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

exec('C:/asd/test.exe', function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());                       
});
```